# I am unable to use TextInputLayout for the EditText

Tags: android, xml

I am unable to use TextInputLayout in my xml file.
So, I am getting a lot of errors.
The screenshot of dependencies and exceptions have been added.
I am trying to use TextInputLayout for my EditText awhere one is for e-mail and password[image: Exception in my android Studio] in the login page

[image: Dependencies]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="#e3e3e3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#333333"/>

</RelativeLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/usernameWrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="Username"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: fixing of grammatical errors

Answer (score 0):

Open your application's `build.gradle` & paste below dependencies under dependency section.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

After that, rebuild your projrct.

P.S. :- you will have to wrap `EditText` for password in `TextInputLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try click this icon and select AppCompat theme?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First check your compileSdkVersion inside the build.gradle and set that version in this support library.

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'

And you have also use the TextInputEditText with TextInputLayout like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/usernameWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="Username"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```